# Inner class instance variable shadowing

Tags: java, object, nested, this

Currently, I'm doing the nested classes tutorial from Oracle and at the Shadowing part I have something which I don't understand at all.

The method `methodInFirstLevel`'s second line of execution code printing out the value of `this.x` but in the main method we had already passed in the argument of 23 to the parameter of the method for the new Object instance. So why is that `int x` of `FirstLevel` still back to 1? Shouldn't the `this` keyword refers to the object instance?

```
public class ShadowTest {

public int x = 0;

class FirstLevel {

    public int x = 1;

    void methodInFirstLevel (int x) {
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
        System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
    ShadowTest.FirstLevel f1 = st.new FirstLevel();
    f1.methodInFirstLevel(23);
}

}
```

The output is:

```
x = 23
this.x = 1
ShadowTest.this.x = 0
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `this.x` to be `23`? No where in `methodInFirstLevel` do you assign `this.x = x`;

Comment: There are three results here (which you haven't shown - please edit the code with the sample output) - it's not at all clear to me which line of output you're confused by. `this.x` refers to `FirstLevel.x`, so has a value of 1. `ShadowTest.this.x` refers to `x` in the instance of `ShadowTest`, so it's 0.

Comment: @user2341963 thanks mate now I know my mistake cheers.

Answer (score 1):

there were no assignments happening in this block of code.

```
void methodInFirstLevel (int x) {
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
        System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
    }
```

the parameter x was never assigned to this.x or ShadowTest.this.x ,
thus both values remain the same.

to change this.x value to 23 you have to set it like

```
this.x =x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign `x` value to `this.x` other wise it will keep the its value as it is.

I think following example will help you to understand the scopes within regular inner classes.

```
class OuterSuper{
    int a=100;
}
class InnerSuper{
    int a=200;
}
class Outer extends OuterSuper{
    int a=300;

    void mOuter(){
        System.out.println("mOuter..");
    }
    class Inner extends InnerSuper{
        int a=400;

        void mInner(){
            int a=500;
            System.out.println("mInner..");
            System.out.println("Local a :"+a);  // This will access the scope within mInner() method    
            System.out.println("Inner a :"+this.a); // This will access the scope of Inner class
            System.out.println("Outer a :"+Outer.this.a);   // This will access outer class scope
            System.out.println("Inner Super a :"+super.a); // this will access super class of inner
            System.out.println("Outer Super a :"+Outer.super.a); // this will access super class of outer
        }
    }
}   

class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Outer.Inner iob=new Outer().new Inner();
        iob.mInner();   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to user2341963 then I realized my negligence for missing out that there's not a single constructor provided to suggest this.x = x